# Why doesn't my code of collapsing margins work?

Tags: html, css

I wrote a simple html file to see how collapsing margins in css work, but I didn't get expected answer. First I'll show you my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Collapsing Margins Testing</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        
        .first {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        
        .second {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</html>

<body>
   <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0051/4802/products/mona-2_1024x1024.jpg?v=1447180277" alt="github cat" class="first">
 
   <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0051/4802/products/mona-2_1024x1024.jpg?v=1447180277" alt="github cat" class="second">
  
</body>
```

I have set right margin of first image 10px and left margin of second image 20px respectively. I expect there to be 20px between the right of first image and left of second image as only bigger margin takes effect in collapsing margins. But when I inspect it in Google developer tools, the space between them are 30px(10px+20px). What's wrong with it? Or do I have a wrong understanding of collapsing margins?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, margin collapsing only works on `block` elements.

Answer (score 3):

- Margin Collapsing works only on Block level elements.
- Only top and bottom margins collapse, Right & Lefts don't.
- An element's bottom margin and it's next elements top margins are collapsed.

It's very well explained here : https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Just a tip : Google enough before posting questions!

Answer (score 1):

Already pointed out by Sandip.

**Margin collapsing works only on block level elements.**

**And also top and bottom margins collapse. Collapsing doesn't work for right and left margin.**

Just for your clarity I edited your code snippet to **replace img with block level elements** and also **replaced margin left and right with top and bottom** so that you can see the margins collapse. The same will not happen for left and right margin.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Collapsing Margins Testing</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .first, .second  {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        
        .first {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            background: green;
        }
        
        .second {
            margin-top: 20px;
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</html>

<body>
   <div class="first">aaa</div>
 
   <div class="second">bbb</div>
  
</body>
```